# Residual plot by categorical independent variable only provides residuals for some categories

Tags: r, lme4, diagnostics, multilevel-analysis

Apologies in advance if I haven't formatted this correctly, this is my first question on SO.

I have run a series of multilevel models using lme4 in R. My outcome variables are continuous and I have one categorical level-two predictor variable with multiple categories (region of the US: Midwest, Northeast, South, West) as well as a series of time-varying covariates. When I run this code,

```
m5 <- lmer(percentfemale~ timecat1 + region + sizelogc + 
         perLatinxc.lag8 + perBlackc.lag8 + 
         femincomedisc.lag8 + femLFPdisc.lag8 + fememploydisc.lag8 + femedudisc.lag8 +
         (1 + timecat1|AJID), data=data, REML=F)
```

I get the following results (reduced for space):

```
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  8182.5   8269.8  -4075.2   8150.5     1722 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.4726 -0.3921 -0.0245  0.3687  6.4414 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 AJID     (Intercept) 12.70271 3.5641       
          timecat1     0.04184 0.2045   0.44
 Residual              2.16582 1.4717       
Number of obs: 1738, groups:  AJID, 531

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)         1.088e+01  3.544e-01  30.696
timecat1            1.086e-01  1.252e-02   8.679
regionNortheast    -2.337e+00  4.749e-01  -4.920
regionSouth         6.269e-01  4.472e-01   1.402
regionWest          1.079e+00  4.807e-01   2.245
```

When I plot the residuals by the independent variables, however, I only have residuals for two of the four regions (see below).

```
xyplot(resid(m5) ~ region, data=data, jitter.x=T, abline=0, type=c("p", "g"))
```

[Residuals plotted on y-axis, Midwest, Northeast, South, West plotted on x-axis, residuals only available for South and West regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPX87.png)

I have no missing data in the region variable and am at a loss as to why I would have estimates for region without corresponding residuals. Why might this be the case?

EDIT2:

```
m5 <- lmer(percentfemale~ timecat1 + region + sizelogc + 
        (1 + timecat1|AJID), data=egdata, REML=F)

xyplot(resid(m5) ~ region, data=data, jitter.x=T, abline=0, type=c("p", "g"))

> dput(egdata)
structure(list(AJID = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 
68L, 68L, 68L, 79L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 97L, 116L, 
116L, 116L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 148L, 148L, 
148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 
152L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 
168L, 168L, 168L, 171L, 171L, 171L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 
176L, 176L, 176L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 183L, 
183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 
191L, 197L, 197L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 225L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 
235L, 235L, 235L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 237L, 238L, 
238L, 238L, 238L, 238L, 238L, 238L, 238L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 
245L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 
265L, 265L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 273L, 273L, 
273L, 273L, 273L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 
279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 280L, 280L, 280L, 280L, 280L, 280L, 
284L, 284L, 284L, 284L, 284L, 284L, 284L, 286L, 286L, 286L, 286L, 
286L, 286L, 286L, 286L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 
296L, 313L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 
345L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 352L, 363L, 363L, 365L, 365L, 365L, 365L, 
365L, 365L, 365L, 365L, 369L, 369L, 369L, 369L, 374L, 374L, 374L, 
374L, 374L, 374L, 374L, 385L, 385L, 385L, 385L, 385L, 385L, 385L, 
391L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 416L, 416L, 416L, 416L, 
416L, 416L, 416L, 417L, 417L, 417L, 417L, 417L, 417L, 417L, 423L, 
423L, 423L, 423L, 423L, 423L, 423L, 429L, 429L, 429L, 429L, 429L, 
429L, 434L, 434L, 434L, 434L, 434L, 434L, 441L, 441L, 441L, 441L, 
441L, 441L, 441L, 441L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 
447L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 453L, 454L, 
454L, 454L, 454L, 454L, 454L, 466L, 466L, 466L, 466L, 466L, 466L, 
466L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 482L, 482L, 506L, 506L, 
506L, 510L, 510L, 510L, 510L, 510L, 513L, 513L, 513L, 513L, 513L, 
513L, 513L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 525L, 525L, 
525L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 547L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 
563L, 563L, 563L, 563L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 577L, 
580L, 580L, 580L, 580L, 580L, 580L, 580L, 586L, 586L, 586L, 586L, 
586L, 586L, 586L, 598L, 598L, 598L, 598L, 598L, 598L, 598L, 598L, 
602L, 602L, 602L, 602L, 602L, 602L, 602L, 603L, 603L, 603L, 617L, 
617L, 617L, 617L, 617L, 617L, 617L, 617L, 630L, 630L, 630L, 630L, 
630L, 630L, 630L, 636L, 636L, 641L, 641L, 641L, 641L, 641L, 641L, 
641L), percentfemale = c(7.834101382, 8.612440191, 8.173076923, 
9.030837004, 10.81081081, 12.15932914, 15.47861507, 13.06818182, 
13.51351351, 6.010928962, 5.825242718, 8.5, 9.708737864, 9.302325581, 
9.5, 12.29946524, 12.06896552, 6.802721088, 6.622516556, 7.042253521, 
8.843537415, 7.843137255, 7.792207792, 11.25, 11.11111111, 10.85271318, 
4.972375691, 6.179775281, 4.651162791, 4.954954955, 6.392694064, 
4.867256637, 3.555555556, 5.172413793, 13.63636364, 13.97058824, 
12.40875912, 5.925925926, 6.25, 7.692307692, 7.586206897, 0.666666667, 
6.756756757, 8.904109589, 6.25, 6.94980695, 8.148148148, 10.98039216, 
9.318996416, 8.865248227, 9.863945578, 10.52631579, 8.088235294, 
11.64383562, 12.10191083, 10.625, 13.0952381, 12.4260355, 7.246376812, 
9.289617486, 10.44776119, 11.01321586, 16.04938272, 14.71861472, 
12.07207207, 15.55763824, 18.0734856, 17.56756757, 17.72639692, 
19.07020873, 19.71014493, 17.64705882, 18, 18.25396825, 19.13043478, 
16.31944444, 17.79935275, 20, 22.11838006, 19.77077364, 20.32967033, 
19.66292135, 12.5, 14.59074733, 17.66666667, 19.62905719, 17.64705882, 
16.09042553, 16.43646409, 6.060606061, 7.947019868, 7.638888889, 
11.9205298, 13.15789474, 12.58741259, 6.091370558, 7.929515419, 
12.38095238, 12.82051282, 12.88888889, 14.52991453, 15.49295775, 
12.5984252, 12.90322581, 14.17322835, 13.17829457, 14.92537313, 
9.803921569, 3.333333333, 5.109489051, 3.496503497, 3.821656051, 
6.060606061, 9.756097561, 9.85915493, 2.857142857, 2.142857143, 
4.516129032, 4.268292683, 5.769230769, 7.407407407, 7.317073171, 
7.894736842, 5.365853659, 7.798165138, 9.482758621, 10.86956522, 
9.777777778, 10.24590164, 11.29032258, 10.67961165, 9.615384615, 
9.322033898, 9.649122807, 10.08403361, 4.615384615, 4.761904762, 
6.25, 5.303030303, 7.8125, 5.882352941, 5.454545455, 8.620689655, 
7.352941176, 9.032258065, 10.97560976, 9.036144578, 6.870229008, 
9.459459459, 14.36464088, 11.5, 13.90134529, 18.4, 16, 8.571428571, 
8.771929825, 6.194690265, 5.504587156, 6.796116505, 11.03117506, 
19.47743468, 12.07289294, 12.9740519, 15.49295775, 16.42411642, 
16.99604743, 19.1681736, 6.034482759, 14.28571429, 6.923076923, 
9.929078014, 9.433962264, 8.074534161, 9.941520468, 13.77245509, 
7.01754386, 8.333333333, 7.851239669, 4.827586207, 4.861111111, 
7.092198582, 9.868421053, 10.1910828, 10.96774194, 13.66459627, 
9.386776293, 10.94023069, 12.86926995, 14.01687216, 15.68885959, 
17.43400859, 16.4295393, 15.56459817, 5.696202532, 5.921052632, 
19.44444444, 8.024691358, 7.142857143, 6.951871658, 7.692307692, 
6.179775281, 9.482758621, 4.761905, 3.703704, 4.950495, 2.912621, 
6.930693, 5.447471, 7.142857, 9.056604, 13.42513, 16.14583, 17.77379, 
17.54967, 17.65677, 9.565217, 6.306306, 8.181818, 5.340114, 7.124352, 
7.549669, 12.74876, 13.29752, 14.33311, 15.43027, 15.96702, 7.758621, 
7.968127, 10.16949, 9.60961, 2.424242, 15.34091, 10.30928, 4.6875, 
5.050505, 7.009346, 7.906977, 2.9615, 3.616637, 10.94527, 11.86903, 
15.31532, 17.4939, 20.42042, 0, 0, 0, 1.694915, 3.225806, 3.149606, 
5, 1.183432, 1.694915, 2.717391, 2.312139, 0.9478673, 2.45098, 
3.012048, 0, 1.734104, 2.564103, 3.5, 3.626943, 3.571429, 5.729167, 
1, 0.9803922, 1.818182, 1.818182, 1.694915, 1.709402, 0.862069, 
6.956522, 9.917355, 10.25641, 0, 11.51079, 9.333333, 1.470588, 
3.472222, 4.166667, 4.166667, 6.756757, 7.801418, 0, 7.741935, 
7.643312, 6.962025, 7.594937, 8.823529, 9.333333, 9.677419, 9.574468, 
7.446809, 7.55814, 7.821229, 6.989247, 10.27027, 8.196721, 8.441558, 
5.714286, 5.5, 6.521739, 6, 5.940594, 4.663212, 8.837209, 11.45833, 
4.516129, 3.703704, 4.285714, 5.625, 5.91716, 5.813953, 6.134969, 
11.87335, 12.16545, 12.23529, 12.72321, 12.67606, 15.6746, 15.21739, 
6.930693, 9.677419, 11.2, 11.2782, 12.19512, 9.448819, 10.18519, 
8.490566, 7.894737, 10.15625, 11.19403, 8.917197, 11.68831, 17.51412, 
16.66667, 18.53933, 4.081633, 4.6875, 5.181347, 4.812834, 4.975124, 
3.349282, 4.624277, 0.6369427, 2.857143, 7.142857, 5.454545, 
7.058824, 7.142857, 8.391608, 1.360544, 1.37931, 1.360544, 4.026846, 
4.697987, 6.535948, 5.405405, 7.801418, 5.454545, 6.622517, 5.882353, 
7.18232, 8.571429, 9.589041, 9.846154, 10.81871, 11.47059, 3.90625, 
4.6875, 3.571429, 4.511278, 6.818182, 11.04294, 14.10256, 4.020101, 
3.045685, 2.439024, 3.478261, 3.2, 3.703704, 3.571429, 4.363636, 
3.97351, 4.792332, 5.333333, 5.315615, 7.923497, 7.286432, 10.35387, 
11.32075, 11.50923, 11.9877, 11.8007, 11.60267, 11.66078, 10.52002, 
6.752412, 6.583072, 9.898477, 10.51345, 10.22444, 10.90487, 8.878505, 
13.67521, 16.66667, 17.43119, 10, 10.62802, 12.61682, 13.00813, 
11.78862, 7.33945, 10.69959, 20.95238, 7.438017, 7.5, 8.333333, 
10.32028, 13.35616, 15.24823, 11.67883, 18.30508, 21.59468, 3.902439, 
4.950495, 5.365854, 5.263158, 7, 8.653846, 7.614213), timecat1 = c(-26L, 
-23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, 
-16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, 
-6L, 0L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -6L, -10L, 
-6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, 
-16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -20L, 
-16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 
0L, -13L, -10L, -6L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 
0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 
-10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -6L, 0L, 
-10L, -6L, 0L, -10L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, 
-20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 
-10L, -6L, 0L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 
-10L, -6L, 0L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 
-10L, -6L, 0L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, 
-13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 0L, -26L, -23L, 
-20L, -13L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, 
-23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, 
-13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -16L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -26L, 
-23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -13L, -10L, -6L, -26L, 
-23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, 
-20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, 
-6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, 
-16L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, 0L, 
-23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 
-10L, -6L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, -26L, -23L, -20L, 
-16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, 
-6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -16L, -23L, 
-20L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, 
0L, -23L, -20L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -13L, 0L, -10L, -6L, 0L, 
-26L, -23L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, 
0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, 
-16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, 
-10L, -6L, 0L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, 
-20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -6L, 
0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, 
-16L, -13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, 
-13L, -10L, -6L, 0L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -6L, 0L, -26L, 
-23L, -26L, -23L, -20L, -16L, -13L, -10L, -6L), region = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Midwest", 
"Northeast", "South", "West"), class = "factor"), sizelogc = c(0.408823946, 
0.636182014, 0.663878359, 0.774106962, 0.837491565, 0.81147203, 
0.731559255, 0.989580112, -0.52527906, -0.277305662, -0.02646953, 
-0.011379257, 0.009202568, -0.141848484, -0.110337044, -0.078522425, 
-0.136207762, -0.595759393, -0.282844698, -0.2826483, -0.277326766, 
-0.250742573, -0.245563831, -0.183035124, -0.32184058, -0.287607408, 
0.048395349, -0.092604697, 0.036508019, 0.127815082, 0.155366121, 
0.255766404, 0.173947166, -0.884692994, -0.731071647, -0.394593501, 
-0.316877791, -0.702103128, -0.74801155, -0.646588826, -0.647397051, 
-0.587480728, -0.603441812, -0.601264967, -0.183904487, 0.168725229, 
0.124365995, 0.088979071, 0.14285296, 0.250676301, 0.31927981, 
0.28021636, -0.460329477, -0.384224561, -0.338558779, -0.562322168, 
-0.200129557, -0.076069403, -0.494231029, -0.189163979, -0.110595941, 
0.001720365, 0.121454067, 0.037814992, 1.598396458, 1.552348848, 
1.528920185, 1.633910643, 1.606908979, 1.832432709, 1.57677083, 
-0.640839651, -0.694966643, -0.547000501, -0.149472291, 0.361169794, 
0.451506904, 0.497633974, 0.455591612, 0.556782641, 0.567741169, 
0.559003403, 0.960085349, 1.049901785, 1.093877349, 1.153096098, 
1.25397841, 1.307771936, 1.216469988, -0.340080349, -0.277326766, 
-0.309985406, -0.232080481, -0.22633193, -0.259169473, -0.066114362, 
0.07356142, 0.079348177, 0.189508651, 0.182273574, 0.213919294, 
0.176972887, -0.622986408, -0.655332188, -0.375868374, -0.37900877, 
-0.594707567, -0.776192083, -0.530252871, -0.726032643, -0.399728748, 
-0.408587383, -0.241049151, -0.153805486, -0.432188637, -0.681483841, 
-0.499994734, -0.399728748, -0.363009875, -0.40728457, -0.37386737, 
-0.341941759, -0.327495407, -0.02646953, -0.062299347, -0.018869451, 
-0.025830674, -0.045304574, 0.009124882, -0.222468106, -0.75938432, 
-0.758622686, -0.680881903, -0.705224506, -0.662300858, -0.57205, 
-0.5534199, -0.521425683, -0.512222273, -0.633091239, -0.726886003, 
-0.765333084, -0.673617498, -0.517985978, -0.355459502, -0.328746935, 
-0.357287329, -0.547952449, -0.390596139, -0.155965909, -0.141848484, 
-0.041607712, 0.070160772, 0.081964777, -0.782026797, -0.850996006, 
-0.680881903, -0.726886003, -0.897757669, 0.303072117, 0.499784169, 
0.702821333, 0.801114163, 0.693473185, 0.685994373, 0.914163737, 
0.870120068, -0.641478507, -0.669679706, -0.384224561, -0.4137822, 
-0.165559974, -0.58143934, -0.195452876, -0.273388974, 0.015697784, 
0.03330568, 0.085281529, -0.650093744, -0.36861152, -0.422177711, 
-0.309985406, -0.254654803, -0.314148136, -0.245248134, 2.21254214, 
2.464016344, 2.517465096, 2.561832541, 2.531204875, 2.596658583, 
2.532332869, 2.463416317, -0.762813478, -0.524421951, -0.559536127, 
-0.464267269, -0.367972664, -0.31100774, -0.33366095, -0.336878457, 
-0.78968967, -0.804381978, -0.770484405, -0.820942213, -0.780928444, 
-0.753377405, 0.507649068, 0.90594493, 0.950657497, 0.942646379, 
1.012083374, 0.956143966, 1.041487785, 0.985550557, -0.674065298, 
-0.666992791, -0.442860242, 1.740855448, 2.044544372, 2.029656842, 
2.069429545, 1.968364716, 1.97746863, 1.883613066, 1.896172492, 
0.042455234, 0.173384627, 0.639131166, 0.581430439, -0.55992864, 
-0.223940699, -0.081275017, -0.095328469, -0.041607712, -0.022849423, 
-0.012017382, 1.467743908, 1.517602151, 1.75795099, 1.728731945, 
1.819062624, 1.618562794, 1.394151166, -1.056795911, -0.989847234, 
-0.929836301, -0.819247308, -0.753377405, -0.741592151, -0.933797606, 
-0.639992648, -0.358710449, -0.202247874, -0.272729057, -0.154788807, 
-0.090038867, -0.25450746, -0.58143934, -0.36861152, -0.250608946, 
-0.155965909, -0.19481402, -0.154788807, -0.076069403, -0.867895383, 
-0.793473924, -0.722750187, -0.729635149, -0.660119911, -0.677053629, 
-0.683503065, -0.501432433, -0.529322349, -0.582050305, -0.333739492, 
-0.428790775, -0.36875227, -0.674704154, -0.565689993, -0.575819755, 
-0.640839651, -0.562322168, -0.609914327, -0.929351167, -0.507130454, 
-0.465900522, -0.47544057, -0.523783095, -0.606773931, -0.448369898, 
-0.37287206, -0.503951844, -0.246966411, -0.301428195, -0.227878491, 
-0.118317987, -0.098549089, -0.11347744, -0.24986708, -0.495218164, 
-0.030009357, -0.069790019, -0.015317049, -0.087781263, -0.079206126, 
-0.204449218, -0.302135509, -0.486740125, -0.578166227, -0.584382126, 
-0.461791419, -0.370726974, -0.493575335, -0.399398814, 0.250851418, 
0.597179856, 0.658448481, 0.714387727, 0.820962263, 0.859063513, 
1.053196627, -0.804381978, -0.578112513, -0.660642278, -0.5811315, 
-0.677053629, -0.655332188, -0.827090486, -0.812961133, -0.716472848, 
-0.590621124, -0.489347051, -0.645030442, -0.363648731, -0.250052349, 
-0.319419439, -0.218776516, -0.54880241, -0.282844698, -0.202247874, 
-0.219144811, -0.165946036, -0.090766948, -0.326828121, -0.427965937, 
-0.615670623, -0.578112513, -0.467270885, -0.417979859, -0.528873117, 
-0.549971673, -0.751513923, -0.404058269, -0.494231029, -0.492438146, 
-0.333739492, -0.273088505, -0.410424966, -0.448995755, -0.655332188, 
-0.499575469, -0.122840343, -0.135833432, 0.209243937, 0.371355262, 
0.498310873, 0.539341695, 0.552798626, -0.484530622, -0.460329477, 
-0.410200048, -0.621421565, -0.606773931, -0.262371866, -0.217973717, 
-0.436129248, -0.191277505, -0.088765921, 0.036508019, 0.065294725, 
0.173384627, 0.140030452, -0.128162504, 0.159966049, 0.221644403, 
0.209243937, 0.22036664, 0.614624755, 0.681129799, 1.065212169, 
1.315573819, 1.477612502, 1.56898489, 1.741486445, 1.795245059, 
1.968924143, 2.11464897, 0.14434477, 0.319548119, 0.663544174, 
0.670843847, 0.680632429, 0.731559255, 0.749879332, -0.687899475, 
-0.622986408, -0.73479636, -0.291390402, -0.058788322, 0.020036939, 
0.217706611, 0.239519072, 0.076585244, 0.182078689, 0.051608314, 
-0.199956196, 0.093274675, 0.204646826, 0.288196489, 0.380811597, 
0.324394911, 0.291056575, -0.009041676, 0.268254825, -0.361143441, 
-0.077205048, -0.172647405, -0.015317049, -0.207445767, -0.114297445, 
-0.093907344)), row.names = c(NA, -432L), class = "data.frame")

> str(egdata)
'data.frame':   432 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ AJID         : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 13 51 ...
 $ percentfemale: num  7.83 8.61 8.17 9.03 10.81 ...
 $ timecat1     : int  -26 -23 -20 -16 -13 -10 -6 0 0 -26 ...
 $ region       : Factor w/ 4 levels "Midwest","Northeast",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 ...
 $ sizelogc     : num  0.409 0.636 0.664 0.774 0.837 ...
```

Comment: I cannot tell without seeing your data but could you check if resid(m5) has missing values for those levels, e.g. `aggregate(resid(m5), by = list(factor(data$region)), FUN = function(x) mean(is.na(x)))` (here, I'm checking the percentage of missing/NA residuals by each region)

Comment: @jav I tried to do this and got the following error message: Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

I believe this is due to the structure of the data. The DVs are measured periodically from 1987-2013, but the IVs are every year in that timeframe. The residual list thus has fewer "cases" than does the original dataframe. I was able to create a sample dataframe, but do not know how to make it available here. It's fairly large. Even with a random sample of 9 subjects I have 243 observations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How about just doing `mean(is.na(resid(m5)))`?

Comment: @jav Done, and the result is 0

Comment: Ok, this shows no missing values. Perhaps to make this faster: Could you take the sample you created and wrap it in the function `dput`, e.g. if your sample is called `mysample`, you can do `dput(mysample)` in your console to get a format that you could paste into your post above. This would allow us to reproduce the data and the issue that you are facing. In addition to this, you could also do `str(mysample)` so we could see the structure of the data.

Comment: @jav See above, and thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data that you've provided, I can now see the underlying issue. Your dataset has a number of missing values. As noted in the documentation of this function (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-23/topics/lmer):

> The default action (na.omit, inherited from the 'factory fresh' value of getOption("na.action")) strips any observations with any missing values in any variables.

As such, your model will only leverage rows where there are no missing values. This is the reason you see no residual values for some levels of your data.

To see this yourself, you can run the following to extract only rows that have no missing values:

```
data2 = data[complete.cases(data),]
```

You can see that `data2` is much smaller. Then run `table(data2$region)` to see the levels of region in this smaller dataset.

Please have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309718/how-to-deal-with-missing-data-in-mixed-effects-or-multi-level-models for information on how you might handle this missing data.

Update: Given your new dataset of only complete cases, I do not see the issue again. Perhaps clear your R session and restart? Reproducible code:

```
library(lme4)
library(lattice)
m5 <- lmer(percentfemale~ timecat1 + region + sizelogc +
             (1 + timecat1|AJID), data=egdata, REML=F) 
summary(m5)
xyplot(resid(m5) ~ region, data=egdata, jitter.x=T, abline=0, type=c("p", "g"))
```

[image]

Comment: Again, thanks for all of your help. I see where the missing levels are a problem in the example data I provided, but I did the same thing on my full data and don't think that's the issue. I have 1,738 complete cases with approximately 20% from the Midwest, 20% from the Northeast, 36% from the South, and 24% from the West. I've edited the post again with a new subsample. More (complete) cases, fewer variables, same issue.

Comment: @AliciaJurek, I just tried with your new dataset and I get (what I believe is) the desired graph. Please let me know if that's not what you wanted. If it is, perhaps clear your R session, restart, load your data and try using the code above to see if you can reproduce the graph?